# How can I implicitly pass data to all child components in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is there any way to implicitly pass data to all the child components of a parent? I'm looking for something similar to `context` in React. Here's a quick example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
<body>
    <my-component :my-prop="foo"></my-component>
    <my-component :my-prop="bar"></my-component>
</body>
```

-

```
import MyComponent from './my-component';

new Vue({
    el: 'body',
    components: {
        MyComponent,
    },
});
```

I'd like all of `my-component`'s children to have access to `myProp` without having to pass it down every time. `$root` sounded like a good idea, but then I'd have to new up a vm for every component on my page, which doesn't feel to nice either.

Comment: Can you use events?

Answer (score 0):

From child component you can get parent component property like

this.$parent.myProp

https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Parent-Chain

**Edit: Create function to find property in parents:**

```
getProperty: function(vueComp, propName) {
    var p = vueComp.$parent;
    while (p) {
        if(p.hasOwnProperty(propName)){
        return p[propName];
        }
      p = p.$parent;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Use it like: `var x = getProperty("myProp");`

Comment: That only works for one level though, I'm looking for something to pass down props infinitely.

Comment: @SebastianDeDeyne Then i see only one way - create function to find property. I added it to answer.